# Text to Image in C++

Tags: c++

Are there any ways to convert a text to an image; for example, 'hello world' would result in an image of you a specific font and size that read 'hello world'?

Is there a way to do this in c++ without any third-party libraries? Or, any known third-party libraries that are very minimalistic and lightweight for this purpose?

Comment: "Is there a way to do this in c++ without any third-party libraries?" Sure, just reimplement one of those libraries like FreeType. `freetype-2.5.3.tar.bz2` is just 1703842 bytes so it should not be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write it on Windows (system dependent), you can use the GDI functions to create a device independent bitmap (DIB) and then draw on it using TextOut, and copy the DIB's pixels as an image.